ORM connection behaves differently for two different codes
I had two different codes and I needed to make an ORM connection and create a table out of the given code: 
code 1:
package com.scm.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.*;

@Entity(name = "user") // doing this makes sure that we have to create a table out of it
@Table(name = "users")  // we can set the name of table
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {
    @Id // this sets userId as primary key
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false) // this sets the column name as 'user_name' for the name field
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String about;

    @Column(length = 10000)

    private String profilePic;
    private String phoneNumber;

    // information
    private boolean enabled=false;
    private boolean emailVerified = false;
    private boolean phoneVerified = false;

    // logged in themselves or using google, linkedin, github or others
    private final Providers provider=Providers.SELF;
    private String providerUserId;
}

When I run the above code first keeping every rest of the things same, the code does not create any table in the MMySQL Workbench. But soon after I run the code below, it creates a table with three column id username email 
code 2: 
package com.scm.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users") // Name of the table in the database
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
}

I thought it had something to do with the lombok and commented that part of code but it still would not work. However, if I run code 2 first and then run the code 1 it works and makes the changes in the table and create all the fields in the table users
UPDATE: I think I found the solution, the size for the attribute in the table was too large so I changed it from 10000 to 1000 and it works now.
